# Regular Expression for Checking that whether field contains an email

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I am new to regular expression . I have textbox fields as well as textarea fields and I have to restrict that they should not contains email like following:

- `abc@gmail.com`
- `abcATgmailDOTcom`
- `abcatgmaildotcom`

now I have created the following regular expression for this:

```
^[a-z0-9._-]+(at|AT|@)[a-z0-9._-]{2,}(.|DOT|dot|dOt)[a-z]{2,4}$
```

now this expression checks for the above mentioned possibilites but know the issue is what if the user enter something like this:

```
blablabla  abc@gmail.com
```

how can I check the above scenario ? Kindly help me I am stuck at this thing or if you have any other solution kindly let me know!!!

Comment: @DavidThomas good point. My thought was that it was an email validation question. I need more coffee obviously :)

Comment: client side validation is not a good thing to use in here you know? this should be handled on the server side. but if you'll use both, that'll be OK. Javascript can be deceived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ^ at the beginning and the $ at the end mean that the pattern matches at the beginning and at the end of your text. Just remove the both ^ and the $ so that the pattern will be matched at any location.

You may also consider doing a case insensitive match so that you do not need to check all combinations of at AT aT At, dot, doT, dOt, Dot, dOT, ...

Answer (score 0):

yes this has worked:

[a-z0-9.*-]+(aT|At|at|AT|@)[a-z0-9.*-]{2,}(.|DOT|DOt|DoT|Dot|dOT|dOt|doT|dot)[a-z]{2,}

Comment: use `\.` (before `|DOT`)

Comment: @Croises what will this do?

Comment: you may then mark the question as answered, and preferably use comments instread of answers to report that it worked ;) still you should consider converting your string to lowercase and just do a match with (at|@) and (dot|\.). You have 8 different combinations for 'dot'. note also that you have to escape the . as otherwise it will match all characters

Comment: @RazaChohan `\.` test for dot but `.` only test for any character.